# Хранение строк в приложении

Tags: qt5

Как лучше хранить константные строки в приложении?

С учетом того, что в будущем, будет задача его перевода.

И с целью исключения дублирования строк.

Варианты:

1. Сделать заголовочник в котором хранить все используемые строки в виде констант

   const QString x = QObject::tr("строка");
2. Тоже самое что и в первом пункте но **static**
3. Как то иначе - но тогда как?

Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0):

Пример из моего проекта (не оптимальное решение, но как есть)

заголовочный файл resources.h:

```
#ifndef RESOURCES_H
#define RESOURCES_H
#include <QIcon>
#include <QString>
#include <QKeySequence>

//-- Поскольку дебильная среда разработки Qt не может использовать нормальные ресурсы,
//-- приходится извращаться

extern const QString STR_ADD;
extern const QString STR_ADD_SUB;
extern const QString STR_EDIT;
extern const QString STR_DEL;
extern const QString STR_QFIL;
extern const QString STR_COPY;
```

...

файл resources.cpp:

```
#include <src/common/resources.h>

const QString STR_ADD=QString("Добавить");
const QString STR_ADD_SUB=QString("Добавить к");
const QString STR_EDIT=QString("Изменить");
const QString STR_DEL=QString("Удалить");
const QString STR_QFIL=QString("Фильтр");
const QString STR_COPY=QString("Копировать");
```

может кто и лучше что предложит.

Comment: в чем фишка переноса самих констант из заголовочника?

Comment: Этот заголовок можно включать повсюду - в тех файлах в которых требуется упоминание констант (получается просто как эрзац-хранилище ресурсов). Если Вы их определите в заголовке, то при включении в разные cpp файлы столкнетесь с ошибками на стадии компиляции - типа они уже определены. А так просто ссылки.

Comment: ну, для этих целей существуют конструкции в заголовках

#ifndef DEF_TYPES_H
#define DEF_TYPES_H

или #progma one

или я не прав?

Comment: прав. Я сделал так как сделал, сколько людей - столько стиля кода, спорить не буду.

Comment: На счет стиля - полностью согласен. Просто я думал в такой реализации есть какой то глубокий смысл...

Comment: На самом деле тут есть еще один плюс. Если сделать как я предложил, то данные строки включаются в проект только 1 раз. Если как указал ты - столько раз - сколько компилятор не найдет определение при включении заголовка. То есть строки в результирующем коде будут дублироваться (оптимизация по размеру )))